# How to print weights and bias during training after each epoch

Tags: keras, neural-network, keras-layer

How to print the weights and bias in a neural network after each epoch during training

I have tried the following code:

```
print_weights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: print(merged.layers[1].get_weights()[0][0:5], merged.layers[2].get_weights()[0][0:5]))


merged.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=[loss1, loss2],loss_weights=[alpham, 1 - alpham], metrics=['accuracy'],callbacks = [print_weights])
```

But I am getting the following error:

**ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['callbacks']))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.compile` does not take the callbacks, that is given to `model.fit`.

Comment: Could you kindly see this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050205/train-neural-network-nn-a-by-minimizing-the-loss-of-nn-a-nn-b-where-b-is-ano